# How to split string into groups with matched paranthisisbin IN C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Is there any way to split below mentioned string into groups using regular expression [grouping by  parenthesis ]

```
Input: "[Id]=@id,{buyerid}<>@id,[userid]>@userid,{custid}=@custid,status>1"
```

Conditions:

1.Need to separate similar parenthesis expression in separate csvs and expression  without parenthesis  in separate. Parenthesis will be only in left side of operator.Allowed operators are =,>,<>,<,!=

```
[ anytext              ] = @anytetx
{ anytext              } =@anytetext
anytext withot parathis  =@anytetx
```

2. Left side of operator ,there will be always plain text without any special charter in parenthesis or without parenthesis case but on right side of operator there can text like: @accountid,"accountid" and number and date in #01-01-1983# and bool value true or false
    Output:

```
1. "[Id]=@id,[userid]>@userid"  

2. "{buyerid}<>@id,{custid}=@custid"

3. "status>1"
```

Comment: There is a way to do this without regex. What language are you using?

Comment: Please specify the conditions with more detail. Show us some other examples. What about edge cases? Any exceptions? ... And more importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Specific edge cases to consider: fields containing commas, fields containing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is how you could do it in Python.

1.py:

```
import re

txt='[Id]=@id,{buyerid}<>@id,[userid]>@userid,{custid}=@custid,status>1'

re1='(.*?),' # Command Seperated Values 1
re2='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re3='.*?,' # Uninteresting: csv
re4='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re5='.*?,' # Uninteresting: csv
re6='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re7='(.*?),' # Command Seperated Values 2

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    csv1=m.group(1)
    csv2=m.group(2)
    print "("+csv1+")"+"("+csv2+")"+"\n"
```

2.py:

```
import re

txt='[Id]=@id,{buyerid}<>@id,[userid]>@userid,{custid}=@custid,status>1'

re1='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='.*?,' # Uninteresting: csv
re3='(.*?),' # Command Seperated Values 1
re4='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re5='(\\{custid\\}=@custid)' # Command Seperated Values 2

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    csv1=m.group(1)
    csv2=m.group(2)
    print "("+csv1+")"+"("+csv2+")"+"\n"
```

3.py:

```
import re

txt='[Id]=@id,{buyerid}<>@id,[userid]>@userid,{custid}=@custid,status>1'

re1='.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='(status)' # Word 1
re3='(>)' # Any Single Character 1
re4='(\\d+)' # Integer Number 1

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    word1=m.group(1)
    c1=m.group(2)
    int1=m.group(3)
    print "("+word1+")"+"("+c1+")"+"("+int1+")"+"\n"
```